# Need with a regex that can handle optional substrings

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to use sed to parse version numbers from the output of `git describe`.  The output is in the form:

```
vMAJOR.MINOR[-STRING]-REVISION-HASH
```

`MAJOR`, `MINOR`, and `REVISION` are integers.  `STRING` and `HASH` are arbitrary strings, but I'm only interested in `HASH`.

Examples:

`v0.1-alpha-3-g9c8c402` should return `0 1 3 g9c8c402`

`v0.4-beta-10-g3187e7f-dirty` should return `0 4 10 g3187e7f-dirty`

`v1.0-0-fe35119e` should return `1 0 0 fe35119e`

I was originally using:

`sed 's/v\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)-.*-\([0-9]*\)-\(.*\)/\1 \2 \3 \4/g'`

However, it works only when the optional substring is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work now because it expects two dashes between version end revision, even if no string is present.

Edit: I'm not very familiar with sed regex, you will need a `\?` instead of `?`. I also read that `\?` was only included as a GNU extension, so not sure if it'll help you.

```
v\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)-.*-\?\([0-9]*\)-\(.*\)
```

If the `\?` doesn't work, you could try specifying it as 'zero or one times' like this:

```
v\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)-.*-\{0,1\}\([0-9]*\)-\(.*\)
```

Comment: Ah, I was missing the part about escaping `?`.  `v\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)-\?.*-\([0-9]*\)-\(.*\)` seems to work.  Your solution with the second dash as the optional one causes the revision number to be lost sometimes.

Comment: Oh, yes, that makes sense, it would be included in the `.*`. Thanks for pointing that out, and glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed 's/v\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)-\([^-]*-\)*\([0-9]*\)-\(.*\)/\1 \2 \4 \5/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

with bash regular expressions:

```
while read version; do
    if [[ $version =~ ^v([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)(-[^-]+)?-([0-9]+)-(.+) ]]; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[-2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[-1]} "
    fi
done <<END
v0.1-alpha-3-g9c8c402 
v0.4-beta-10-g3187e7f-dirty 
v1.0-0-fe35119e 
END
```

```
0 1 3 g9c8c402 
0 4 10 g3187e7f-dirty 
1 0 0 fe35119e
```

Perl's non-capturing parentheses `(?:...)`
are useful as well:

```
perl -pe 's/^v([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)(?:-[^-]+)?-([0-9]+)-(.+)/$1 $2 $3 $4/' <<END
v0.1-alpha-3-g9c8c402 
v0.4-beta-10-g3187e7f-dirty 
v1.0-0-fe35119e 
END
```